# What coordinates on Earth would provide the most arable land for a large island?

Tags: alternate-history, climate, geography, agriculture, anthropology

For my Alternate history story, I want a new ethnic group with their own landmass. Said landmass is a perfectly circular island the size of Egypt (area of 1 million square kilometers). This island landmass will have a tall mountain range in the center and the rest will be grassy plains.

Given this criteria, what location on Earth will provide a climate for the island very conducive to arable land? Clearly the poles are the wrong answer. That said, I'm not sure the equator is a good answer either. The island will be a million years old if it matters.

Comment: What is the technology level of the people involved in farming?

Comment: If the natural state of most of the land *on an island* is grassland, there must be something wrong either with the soil (too poor), or with the rain (too little), or with the temperature (too cold).

Comment: @L.Dutch, the ideal farming territory would be great for any level of civilization. It's not like the invention of the tractor has turned Saudi Arabia into a breadabasket or turned Bangladesh into a food importer.

Comment: Note that if you want to have an isolated island, the question which crops they have access to gets really important. Before 1500 the Americas were able to produce significantly less food than comparable climates in Asia/Europe because they didn't have access to rice/wheat/rye.

Comment: It's worth noting that different locations may be good for very different types of cultures, and it's not just a matter of latitude, but also of proximity to the sea, seasonal patterns, terrain, soil... You don't quite grow bananas or pineapples in the same places you would grow wheat...

Comment: The Hawaiian islands are pretty fertile.

Comment: You just need to scale up the Madeira island, or build an archipelago of 1000s of Madeira islands ...

Answer (score 13):

### -37,-125

Dead center of the South Pacific, within the temperate zone. You'd get more arable land if you put your mountain range on the NW edge, but this is where you'd want your island country to be. Additionally, the rest of the world might not even notice it until the 1600's.

Comment: Yes, any mountain range will create a rain shadow. Which ever place OP picks in the end, to maximize the arable land, the most of the "flat" parts should be on the side where wet winds blows from.

Comment: @byMaelstromer: No, not every mountain range will create a rain shadow. First, the mountain range must be located in an area where there is a specific direction from which the wind blows in an overwhelming majority of the time. Second, the mountain range must be long and oriented across the direction of the prevailing wind. (And again, the prevailng wind must be very prevailing.) For a practical counterexample, consider the Alps in Europe. Fairly long mountain chain, quite tall, and no rain shadow to speak of.

Comment: I looked up the prevailing winds in the area, and they tend to come from ESE. Thus, putting the mountains on the NW edge would turn the island into a watershed on the scale of the Mississippi river basin. Unfortunately, this would make the entire island off balance, and would have unpredictable effects if the island were turning on the backs of elephants.

Comment: "the rest of the world" meaning people on the eurasian and american continents. The polynesians would have noticed well before 1600. Maybe that fits OP's "ethnic group"?

Comment: I would suggest examining closely the prevailing ocean and air currents in the area before using this suggestion. As has been noted with other answers, the Gulf stream makes Europe far more habitable than Asia and North America at the same latitudes. The opposite effect could occur with the wrong currents. Easter Island is in the general region and tends to be arid.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, Why "examine closely" when your first act is to throw it all out the window? We're talking about putting a million square kilometers of extra land in the middle of the Pacific Ocean. Do you really think that this question warrants a supercomputer simulation?

Comment: @craq, I suspect that Polynesia would be like the Caribbean for these people. 1600 is when Europe first sent out ships capable of surviving these long voyages. China and Japan knew that New Zealand existed, but didn't consider it worth their effort to colonize.

Comment: "China and Japan knew that New Zealand existed" do you have a source for that? My understanding was that while polynesians sailed back and forth between the islands in the main group, NZ was quite isolated, so that most of polynesia may not have been aware it existed. I was also not aware of polynesian knowledge of the islands making its way back to China and Japan. I'd be interested in reading up on it more if there's something I've missed or misunderstood.

Comment: @craq, I'm just going off of various bits on the internet, like this: https://www.chinadaily.com.cn/en/doc/2003-11/08/content_279722.htm I understand that the Chinese had small settlements in Australia, but that's not in my area of historical research.

Comment: I said nothing suggesting a computer simulation. If you have to make ridiculous exaggerations to make your point, you don't have a point to make. And while a circular island the size of Egypt  in the middle of the South Pacific might divert ocean currents some, it will not totally disrupt them, and I say "might" because the real question is are there any strong currents in the area to disrupt? If so, then the Island will indeed be lush. But the Pacific got its name exactly because European explorers *didn't* encounter much of anything moving in that region. That leads to a drier climate.

Comment: @craq, there's a fair chance the Polynesians would have missed it.  -37, -125 is *really* middle-of-nowhere.  The nearest Polynesian settlement was a short-lived colonization of Pitcairn Island, 400 miles off the coast of this hypothetical landmass.  The Polynesians did some impressive island-hopping, but a 400-mile blind jump is long even for them.  Note that the two longest jumps they did -- Easter Island and Hawaii -- both got cut off from mainstream Polynesian culture.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, If you don't think it would take a supercomputer simulation to figure out the effects of this landmass, then I have to recommend that you look into how weather and climate are studied. https://www.nccs.nasa.gov/services/climate-data-services . The other option is that you think I didn't even bother to look into generalized air and water flow in the South Pacific before posting my answer. If that's the case, please present some bit of evidence that suggests that my answer doesn't fit our current data.

Comment: My comment was not about YOU at all. I have no idea what research you've done, and never claimed otherwise. (I still have no idea, because the way you phrased that *could* easily be weasel-wording.) I simply indicated that Peabody Jr should look into it instead of just assuming it was true. And a simple water table is actually a more accurate way to figure out if a current system is going to be majorly disrupted by an island significantly smaller than the current in an empty region, than any simulation, even on a supercomputer. I *know* first hand how simulations work.

Answer (score 10):

**Between 30th and 45th parallel.**

Theses lattitudes gives you what we sometimes call a Mediterranean climate and around-a-year growing season. Closer to the equator will give you first dry zone and then wet tropical zone. Former running the risk of insufficient rainfall, the latter having the growing season interrupted by heavy rainfall.

Go pole-vise and you start seeing the growing season interrupted by regular cold winters.

Put your island few miles north-west from [Madeira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madeira) (32°39′4″N 16°54′35″W) and the Gulf current will keep your climate cozy and stable.

Answer (score 1):

Certain countries have far more arable land than others. There are multiple reasons for this, but geographical location makes a huge difference. There are good reasons that Greenland is generally inhospitable while China has 1.4 billion people.

This map here displays the percentage of arable land by country:

[image: Farming Land Ratio]

The places with the best farmland seem to be Europe, Caribbean, South Asia, and West Africa. I know India and Bangladesh are very fertile thanks to mountain rivers, but overall placing your island next to a country with lots of arable land will generally lead to your new landmass also having the right climate and other attributes to have lots of cultivated land. An Egypt-sized island can't really fit in Europe, but a large island just south of India (Delhi is 28.7041° N, 77.1025° E ) or west of Nigeria ( Lagos is 6.5244° N, 3.3792° E ) would be good locations for your island.

Comment: Nice map! What’s the source? I’d love to see whether one exists (or could be made) with a finer breakdown for large countries.

Comment: This map would be a lot more useful broken down into smaller regions, it's a bit pointless for these purposes using political boundaries

Comment: @TimPederick A reverse image search brought me to [Wikipedia/Wikimedia commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Arable_land_percent_world.png?uselang=fr), so it's a start. Now to know where the data was taken from... If we check the wiki's pages, it looks like it comes from [the World Factbooks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_World_Factbook), edition 2006. Seems hard to link this statement and the map together to make it really sound, however. Still, I wouldn't be surprised there's no pure geographical map of this, since economy map usually focus on geopolitics.

Comment: This map is utterly and completely useless. The climatic and soil conditions prevalent in the beatifully purple Ukraine do not stop abruptly at the boundary between the Ukrainian Soviet Socialist Republic and the Russian Soviet Socialist Federative Republic. In fact, they continue north-eastwards over an area about as large as Ukraine! And the same can be said about the boundary between blue Germany and purple Poland; remember that the boundary was only placed in its current position by the Americans and the Russians in 1945.

Comment: I think that this map represents the area that each country dedicates to row crop production. Brazil, for example, is shown as only 5-9% while the country dedicates almost half of its land mass to agriculture in general. If you remove the geopolitical factors, the real crop land potential of the country is even higher.

Comment: @AlexP Is there a reason for using the terms "the Ukrainian Soviet Socialist Republic"  and " the Russian Soviet Socialist Federative Republic",  both of which ceased to exist in 1991, instead of "Ukraine" and "the Russian Federation"? Is it because the map outlines predates their dissolution?

Comment: @traktor: The original purpose was of that line was purely administrative; it was established as the boundary between the Ukrainian SSR and the Russian SSFR. It did not exist before. When it was established, nobody even considered the possibility that one day it would become the border between two independent countries. Yes, history is prone to practical jokes, and eventually it came to pass that the hastily set up administrative boundary became an international border, but that was many years later.

Comment: @CesarCanassa Large part of Brazil is not (yet) made of arable land: https://www.mdpi.com/sustainability/sustainability-14-02563/article_deploy/html/images/sustainability-14-02563-g001-550.jpg the potential is large, if you chop down the forest like Europe did in the previous millenia, but the soil left behind is not necessarily arable land

Comment: The lack of cultivation in this map may also be political rather than climatic or soil richness.

Comment: And (@AlexP) [Canada](https://atlas.gc.ca/lcct/en/index.html) shows the opposite problem - one colour on that map but the south is a major wheat-growing area, while the north has large barren and inhospitable areas

Comment: @Tortliena The image search gnomes must’ve been kinder to you than to me! I got a lot of similar-looking maps (funnily enough, there are a lot of maps showing countries in various colours!!), but only one exact match, that being from some paper that mentioned the World Factbook but didn’t elaborate further.

Answer (score 0):

Anything around the same lattitude as England/Europe or New Zealand.

You get the best of both worlds - enough rain that you rarely worry about drought, enough summer that the crops grow pretty regularly.

Add on top of that either some Volcanic soil with flat-ish fields or at least rolling hills - and you are onto a winner.

Comment: England has always been a net importer of food. Not exactly an agricultural paradise. Even with modern technology, most of the land in England is *at best* suitable for pasture. With real numbers, about 70% of the land area of England is usable for agriculture in any way, and of this about 60% is only usable as pasture. Only about 12% of the land area of England is used for arable agriculture. See the [nice publication](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1106562/AUK_Evidence_Pack_2021_Sept22.pdf) of the UK Department for Food.

Comment: Note that parts of Western Europe get the benefit of the Gulf Stream which warms the climate compared to what you would normally have at those latitudes. Remember that France is at the same latitudes as the Canadian provinces, probably not the best example of an ideal climate for agriculture. New Zealand is quite a bit closer to the Equator, about the same as Spain rather than England, and I'm not sure its arable agriculture is very developed compared to other countries.

Comment: At the same latitude as England, on Hudson Bay, they have substantial issues with *polar bears*.  The Gulf Stream does all the work to keep England warm (as @jcaron notes)

Comment: @jcaron: Romania and Ukraine are about at the same latitude as France, with no Gulf Stream whatsoever, and I can assure you that wheat grows very well. Ukraine was a major wheat exporter before the current trouble with the Russian Empire. (And anyway, whatever influence the Gulf Stream *might* have on the western coast of France, it definitely does not extend over all the country. Moreover, as far as I know, the western coast of France does not have a particularly warm and balmy climae, not at all.)

Comment: Grew. "grew pretty regularly" .Its in the past now.